# Test regex expression for the model property

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

This is part of my model

```
[RegularExpression(@"^([a-z][a-z0-9.-]+)\\((?! +\r?$)[a-z0-9 ]+)\r?$", ErrorMessage = @"Enter the account in domain\account format.")]
    [ScaffoldColumn(true)]
    [DisplayName("Account Name")]
    string Col_DomainName { get; set; }
```

I want to write a UnitTest where I can test this. How do I do that? I am using NUnit.

Thanks!

Comment: It is very unclear what the question is...

Comment: You don't need to write unit tests for classes like `RegularExpression` and others. You should write unit tests for the code you have written. This is the mistake usually people who just starts into unit testing.

Comment: I wrote the regular expression to validate the field for account name. I should be able to test if my regular expression is valid. I do not understand why i should not test for that. I am not testing if the actual validation works i am testing my regular expression.